# How to get id and show value in a table on index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, nested-attributes, cocoon-gem

I can only view the child values in the "show" template using:

```html
<% @guest.plusones.each do |plus| %>
  <%= plus.name %>
  <%= plus.oldness %>
<% end %>
```

I now need display these values in a table on the "index" template.

How can I do this?

See tables and relationship below:

```html
Plusone table

+--------------+---------+----------+    
|     name     | Oldness | guest_id |
+--------------+---------+----------+    
| Tom Jnr      | Child   |        4 |
| Nancy Miller | Adult   |        5 |
| Ace Flame    | Adult   |        6 |
+--------------+---------+----------+

Guests table
+----+------------+-----------------+
| id |    name    |     Message     |
+----+------------+-----------------+
|  4 | Tom Snr    | Congratulations |
|  5 | Rob Miller | Congrats        |
|  6 | May Flame  | Wow Amazing     |
+----+------------+-----------------+
```

As there anything that I need to add in the GuestController index method?

Comment: Please show how you define inistial `f` (form tag). Stacktrace would be useful as well.

Comment: What you added is a server log, not the error backtrace. :)

Comment: @BroiSatse I hope that I've added the correct trace this time :)

Comment: Updated and added database table relations, any help will be appreciated. @BroiSatse

Answer (score 0):

Try to organize your code like this so you can debug your error easily:

#### views/guests/index.html.erb

```
<%= render @guests %>
```

#### views/guests/_guest.html.erb

```
<%= guest.name %>
<%= render guest.plusones %>
```

#### views/plusones/_plusone.html.erb

```
<%= plusone.name %>
```